# top process state column under FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, process, top

When running top interactively, I can see various words in the state column :

- nanslp, biord, select, uwait, lockf, pause, kqread, piperd, sbwait ...

Some like nanslp or kqread are self explanatory, others are not.

Tried Mr man pages :

> STATE is the current
>          state (one of "START", "RUN" (shown as "CPUn" on SMP systems), "SLEEP",
>          "STOP",  "ZOMB",  "WAIT",  "LOCK"  or  the  event  on which the process
>          waits), C is the processor number on which  the  process  is  executing
>          (visible  only  on  SMP systems)

Tried search engines :

- [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966559/what-does-the-sbwait-process-state-imply-in-freebsd-top)
- [mailing lists archives](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2006-December/138062.html)

Where may I get a complete list of possible process state under FreeBSD 9, and their meanings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit further in the `top` man page there is:

> ```
>    If  a  process is in the "SLEEP" or "LOCK" state, the state column will
>    report the name of the event or lock on which the process  is  waiting.
>    Lock  names  are  prefixed  with an asterisk "*" while sleep events are
>    not
> ```

So basically, all the non-capital "STATE", non prefixed with an asterisk are sleep events name.

These label are set in FreeBSD kernel, so this is where you should go to find their meaning.
Sadly there is no nice summary as the event name is set by the `sleep` calls.

For instance, somewhere in `/usr/src/sys/kern/sys_pipe.c` in the `pipe_read` function:

`error = msleep(rpipe, PIPE_MTX(rpipe), PRIBIO | PCATCH, "piperd", 0);`

Or in `/usr/src/sys/kern/sys_pipe.c` in the `kern_nanosleep` function:

`error = tsleep(&nanowait, PWAIT | PCATCH, "nanslp", tvtohz(&tv));`

Answer (score 0):

from `man 1 ps`:

```
......
mwchan   The event name if the process is  blocked  normally,  or  the
        lock name if the process is blocked on a lock.  See the wchan
        and lockname keywords for details.
......
```

So I now quote https://wiki.freebsd.org/WaitChannels from the google search result :

| Wait Channel | Description |
| --- | --- |
| biord | Waiting for a disk read operation to complete |
| biowr | Waiting for a disk write operation to complete |
| nfsreq | Waiting for a reply to an NFS request |
| wdrain | Waiting for pending writes to a file to drain to disk |
| flushbuf | Waiting for pending writes to a file to drain to disk so the pages can be flushed from RAM via posix_fadvise(2) |
| sbwait | Waiting for data to arrive on a socket, e.g. a blocking read(2) on a socket |
| kqread | Waiting for an event to arrive on a kqueue |
| select | Waiting for an event to trigger on a file descriptor via select(2) or poll(2), usually a socket |
| piperd | Waiting for data to arrive on a pipe, i.e. a blocking read(2) |
| pipewr | Waiting for room to write data into a pipe, i.e. a blocking write(2) |
| fifoor | Waiting in a blocking read-only open of a FIFO (O_RDONLY) for another process to open a writable descriptor on this FIFO (O_RDWR or O_WRONLY) |
| fifoow | Waiting in a blocking write-only open of a FIFO (O_WRONLY) for another process to open a readable descriptor on this FIFO (O_RDWR or O_RDONLY) |
| wait | Waiting for a child process to exit, e.g. a shell waiting for a command to complete |
| ttyin | Waiting to read data from a terminal, e.g. idle shell for an ssh session or xterm |
| ttyout | Waiting to write data to a terminal |
| pause | Waiting for a signal (tcsh uses this instead of "wait") |
| nanslp | Waiting for a specified amount of time to pass, e.g. "sleep 1" |
| ucond | Waiting for a userland condition variable (pthread_cond_wait()) |
| getblk | Waiting to access file data that is being accessed by another thread |
| ufs | Waiting to read from a file or directory on a UFS filesystem that is being written to by another thread, or waiting to write to a local file or directory that is being read or written by another thread |
| nfs | Same as "ufs" but for an NFS file or directory. Often if you see this it's because the other thread is blocked in "nfsreq". |
| zfs | Same as "ufs" but for a ZFS file or directory. |

^T with sysctl kern.tty_info_kstacks=1 may show even more useful info than this wait channel. Like differentiating between poll() and select().